# How to make online store for a specific of time?

Tags: wordpress

I am designing online products store using woocommerce plugin in wordpress. but now I want to set that Customer can order products only in morning between 9 am to 12 pm and in evening between 4 pm to 8 pm so How Can I do this?

Comment: This is a better question for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions, you can disable gateways so customer can't buy (and then change the default message)

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'disable_gateway_time', 99, 1 );

function custom_gateway( $gateways ){
    $current_time = date('H');

    // If ok return $gateways
    if ( ( $current_time > 9 && $current_time < 12 ) || ( $current_time > 16 && $current_time < 18 ) )
        return $gateways;

    // Else return empty array
    return array();
}
```

Or you can also use another hook in order to display an error message (if statement can be simplified)

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_process' , 99);

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // You can make your own control here
    $current_time = date('H');
    if ( ! (( $current_time > 9 || $current_time < 12 ) && ( $current_time > 16 || $current_time < 18 )) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The store is closed' ), 'error' );
}
```

Don't forget to check you timezone on php ini or you can add before date() function.

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );
```